# Peak symbol with Word

Tags: microsoft-word

Using MS Word 2010, I need to print a 'peak' symbol, which is a circumflex accent on top of *any* letter (not only vowels), something like this :

```
^
s
```

Is there a way to do it without using the equation editor ?

Comment: For as far as I knnow, you can't except with the equation editor or by inserting symbols.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type first the letter, then type U+302 and hit Alt X (i.e. press X while keeping the Alt key pressed down). The part U+ may be omitted if the letter is not in the range A–F or X.

This will put U+0302 COMBINING CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT after the letter. In rendering, it will appear as a character placed above the preceding character, something like this (I’m assuming your browser can deal with this): v̂.

Word 2007 can handle such situations mostly OK, selecting the placement of the circumflex according to the height of the base letter. I expect Word 2010 to do even better. But there are still potential problems. Perhaps most importantly, you should make sure that the font you are using contains U+0302. Support is rather wide, but not universal, see
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/302/fontsupport.htm

For example, if your text font is Palatino Linotype, the results will be very bad: since the font does not contain U+0302, Word will pick it up from a different font, and both the shape and the placement of the circumflex can be all wrong then.

Even for some non-vowel characters, a “precombined” character with the circumflex accent is available. For example, instead of ŝ (s followed by U+0302), you can enter U+15D Alt X and get ŝ (= U+015D). In modern versions of Word, the appearance is normally the same as with the one using U+0302, but the renderings might work, so it is probably safest to use U+0302 for all combinations, if you cannot use precombined characters for all combinations that you need.

Comment: I just want to mention, as I'm using the french version of Word, that I had to use ALT + C instead of ALT + X to get the expected result.

Comment: @Jérôme, thanks for the information—it’s good to know about this feature. I first thought it might be a configuration issue or something special, but the document Unicode 5.0 en pratique – Concepts de base et terminologie http://hapax.qc.ca/dunod/Unicode_Chap_1.pdf describes it as a general difference between language versions: English version of Word uses Alt X, French version uses Alt C.

Answer (score 0):

You can just press the key for the symbol (the location depends on your keyboard layout) and then i, the symbol will be automatically inserted on top of the letter.

Comment: thanks. My question was not clear enough : I would like to be able to put the accent on top of any letter, not only vowels.