# Need for centered circumflex over Φ (the "phi" character) using Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, special-characters

There was a [helpful answer](https://superuser.com/a/419559/138343) 3 years ago about putting a circumflex over a letter by using (optional U)+302 and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>. That worked! But when I try it with the phi character, the circumflex leans on the top right side of the symbol, kind of like a baseball cap (see screenshot below). How do I center the circumflex in this case?

[image: 1]

Comment: Next time please link to the original question/answer to save us the trouble of guessing and searching for it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Select the two characters (phi and circumflex) > right-click > Font... > Advanced tab.
2. Set **Spacing** to *Condensed* and then change the value to the right by a few pts, OK your way out and check the results:

   [image: 1]
3. If the circumflex is still not centered properly, go back and edit the value till you get it right. Eventually it should look like this:

   [image: 2]